# What happened to real time tracking in Latitude?

Tags: google-maps, google-latitude

What happened to the real time tracking of friends in Latitude? The feature used to be there, but I cant find it anymore

Comment: Can you be more descriptive because its right here for me.

Comment: I can still see where my friends were several minutes ago, but I can't find the option of getting updates every several seconds. There used to be an option "track this person for 15minutes" but I cant find it now

Comment: OK I understood. I assumed different thing when I said that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According tho [this post](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/maps/google-maps-for-mobile/oOnQX0fQHj8), that feature was removed as of version 5.10 of Google Maps app because it was never properly working.

Comment: This is very upsetting for me :( Loved real-time updating, and only now does someone I care for following have an Android :-/

Comment: Google rep said that this feature was not working, and most of the time did the opposite, so I wouldn't miss it if I were you :)

Comment: I find their reasoning hard to believe

Answer (score 0):

You can just press "refresh"-- and it will really give you second-by-second changes so long as the person you're looking at has their GPS on.

If location is set to "Network"- then it only updates when they change towers.

This is much more battery-efficient, it seems.

Comment: Yea, I am aware that GPS is expensive since its an additional chip to be enabled. While using mobile phone towers is given effectively for free, since you're going to be connected to the cell towers already.